# I load the data in the componentDidMount but it loads the data every time it's rendered, how do I avoid that behavior?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I don’t know how to avoid a component to load the data twice, I need it to load the data once, and every time it is rendered, I don’t want it to reload the data.

I placed the data loading in the componentDidMount, but each time it is rendered, it calls the data loading

What can I do?

I tried using a Boolean in the redux store, with no success

It wasn’t happening, but after several changes, it started to happen and I don’t know the reason
What do you suggest me to do?

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: That method only fires on first mount, not each rerender? May you share a [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: How do I add more code?, here in the comments it doesn't fit

Comment: Is that loading data twice or more?

Comment: If the data is loaded only twice, it may be because of using <React.StrictMode>. More info, [here](https://mariosfakiolas.com/blog/my-react-components-render-twice-and-drive-me-crazy#what-is-reactstrictmode).
If it's not the case, it could be caused by using key prop in CountryCard component.

Comment: Don’t add code in the comments. Edit the question

Answer (score 1):

To prevent loading the data more than once, you can check first if the data is available. If it is, don't fetch it again.

```js
   componentDidMount = () => {  
     if(this.props.countries && this.props.countries.length > 0) {
       // data is loaded, don't fetch it again
       return
     }
     // data not available, fetch it
     this.props.loadCountries()
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

useEffect(() =>{}, []) is the simplest answer her in my opinion..